# Iterate over CSV and change index by row value

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV containing the following:

```
ID    Name    Series    Value
250   A       3         20
250   A       3         40
250   A       3         60
251   B       4         16
251   B       4         18
251   B       4         24
251   B       4         42
```

The `Series` column denotes how many elements belong to one another, so taking the first row (not header row), the `Series = 3`. So I need to gather the number of rows specified by `Series`, inclusive of the current row. Such that they are grouped like so (by `Value`):

`[(20, 40, 60), (16, 18, 24, 42)]`

Essentially, I am moving down through the CSV sequentially, while `Series` tells me how many of the next rows (including the current one) to gather. If we use the first row again, the value is `3`, so my grouping must total `3` rows starting at the current row.

I've read in the CSV and converted it from a `Reader` to `List`, but cant quite come up with a solution for actively changing the index of iteration over the rows based upon the value found in series. If I try:

`for row in rows...`

I end up iterating over every row, I would have to change the value of `rows` and altering a list while iterating over it is a bad idea. If I try:

`for x in range(1, len(rows)...`

I cannot devise a method to change where the current `x` should be.

Comment: Are the values in the `Series` column already grouped? I.E., it won't go `2,2,2, 3,3,3, 2,1,...`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No. `Series` denotes from the current row, how many more rows go together. So if the first row is `3`, I need a group of that row, plus the next `2` rows which would give me `3` total rows. Numbers can repeat again later in the file but are not part of the previous groupings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't use pandas, just use the typical grouping idiom using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import csv
import collections

with open("path/to/file.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    grouped = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for row in reader:
        grouped[row['Series']].append(int(row['Value']))
```

This will give you a handy dictionary from series to values:

```
In [26]: grouped
Out[26]: defaultdict(list, {'3': [20, 40, 60], '4': [16, 18, 24, 42]})
```

If you *must* have a list of tuples:

```
In [28]: list(map(tuple, grouped.values()))
Out[28]: [(20, 40, 60), (16, 18, 24, 42)]
```

If you *were* going to use a `pandas.DataFrame`, I would use:

```
In [35]: [tuple(g.Value) for _,g in df.groupby('Series')]
Out[35]: [(20, 40, 60), (16, 18, 24, 42)]
```

#### Edit After Comments

So, after elaborating on your problem a bit more, there are a couple of approaches. Here's one ugly one, using `itertools.islice` to advance the iterator:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

with io.StringIO(csvstring) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    grouped = []
    for row in reader:
        n = int(row['Series']) - 1
        val = row['Value']
        next_vals = (int(r['Value']) for r in islice(reader, n))
        grouped.append((val,)+ tuple(next_vals))
```

You may also use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
import operator
import csv

with open('path/to/file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    grouped = itertools.groupby(reader, operator.itemgetter('Series'))
    result = []
    for _, g in grouped:
        result.append(tuple(int(r['Value']) for r in g))
```

The results:

```
In [48]: result
Out[48]: [(20, 40, 60), (16, 18, 24, 42)]
```

Note, just for the purposes of illustration, you don't need itertools to do this, you could just for-loops in the following way:

```
import csv

with open('path/to/file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    grouped = []
    for row in reader:
        n = int(row['Series']) - 1
        val = row['Value']
        sub = [val]
        for _ in range(n):
            sub.append(int(next(reader)['Value'])) #advance the iterator using next
        grouped.append(tuple(sub))
```

Answer (score 2):

how about using pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
unique = tuple(df['Series'].unique())
data = [tuple(df[df.Series == i].Value) for i in unique]
print(data)
```

output is

```
[(20, 40, 60), (16, 18, 24, 42)]
```

Comment: No access to it on the system being used. Good solution, but need a native one.

Answer (score 1):

Repeating series kindof hurt dicts, so use only lists:

Added repeating series to the data....

---

```
import csv

t = """ID    Name    Series    Value
250   A       3         20
250   A       3         40
250   A       3         60
251   B       4         16
251   B       4         18
251   B       4         24
251   B       4         42
250   A       3        140
250   A       3        160"""


results = list()
tempList = list()
lastKey = None

reader = csv.DictReader(t.splitlines(), skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=' '  )
for row in reader:
    actKey = row["Series"]
    actVal = row["Value"]

    if not lastKey or lastKey != actKey: # new series starts here
        lastKey = actKey
        if tempList:                     # avoids result starting with []
            results.append(tempList)
        tempList = [actVal]              # this value goes into the new list
        continue

    tempList.append(actVal)              # same key as last one, simply add value 


if tempList:
    results.append(tempList)             # if not empty, add last ones to result 

print(results)
```

Output:

```
[['20', '40', '60'], ['16', '18', '24', '42'], ['140', '160']]
```

Comment: Problem with this is that later in the file, a `Series` may be repeated, but the elements dont belong together.

Comment: @pstatix How about you collect all your "cant do this" conditions and add them the the question firsthand .- the solutions to _your_ problem are much easier to come by that way.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I would if his data would contain inner "" that are difficult to parse. He said he already solved the "gathering data in lists" part, so I am just using a quick hack to get data into lists and start from there. I am not really familar with `csv`, what other benefits then parsing do they give me?

Comment: @pstatix fixed, but juanpa's solutions might be the wiser choice.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga nvm reading the module page atm. Iterator, so no  manifestation of data in lists. thats a big + regarding memory and files.

Comment: @PatrickArtner well, it solves all the problems with parsing a csv, e.g. quoting etc. At the end of the day, I tend towards not re-inventing the wheel. But I cheated and used `pandas.read_clipboard` and then did `df.to_csv` to make an *actual* csv out of the data, lol.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga converted it to use `csv` - it is memory wise the smarter overall move - thanks for tipping me that way - most ppl here use huge files and data - I am C# and just pythonic in my freetime so I can get away with using list comprehensions most of the time. the ones asking questions having 1millions rows to do, may not be so fortunate

Comment: @PatrickArtner heh, yeah. I mean, you could have adapted your manual parsing solution to work lazily, however, I look how much more readable the code becomes once you encapsulate the csv-parsing logic. To me, that is the major advantage.